# PostgreSQL 9.4 query tuning

Tags: postgresql-9.4, query-tuning

I have a query that is running too slowly.

```
select c.vm_name,
       round(sum(bytes_sent)*1.8/power(10,9)) gb_sent,
       round(sum(bytes_received)*1.8/power(10,9)) gb_received
  from groups b, 
       vms c, 
       vm_ip_address_histories d, 
       ip_address_usage_histories e
 where b.group_id = c.group_id
   and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
   and d.ip_address = e.ip_address
   and e.datetime >= firstday()
   and d.allocation_date <= last_day(sysdate()) and (d.deallocation_date is null or d.deallocation_date > last_day(sysdate()))
   and b.customer_id = 29
 group by c.vm_name
 order by 1;
```

The function `sysdate()` returns the current system timestamp without a time zone, `last_day()` returns the timestamp that represents the last day of the month.  I created these because Hibernate doesn't like the Postgres  casting notation.

The issue is that the planner is doing full table scans where there are indexes in place.  Here is the explain plan for the above query:

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=1326387.13..1326391.38 rows=1698 width=24) (actual time=13221.041..13221.042 rows=7 loops=1)
   Sort Key: c.vm_name
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1326236.61..1326296.04 rows=1698 width=24) (actual time=13221.008..13221.026 rows=7 loops=1)
         Group Key: c.vm_name
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=1309056.97..1325972.10 rows=35268 width=24) (actual time=13131.323..13211.612 rows=13631 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (d.ip_address = e.ip_address)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.97..6942.24 rows=79 width=15) (actual time=0.249..56.904 rows=192 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.69..41.02 rows=98 width=16) (actual time=0.066..0.638 rows=61 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (c.group_id = b.group_id)
                           ->  Seq Scan on vms c  (cost=0.00..30.98 rows=1698 width=24) (actual time=0.009..0.281 rows=1698 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=2.65..2.65 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=4 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on groups b  (cost=0.00..2.65 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.011 rows=4 loops=1)
                                       Filter: (customer_id = 29)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 49
                     ->  Index Scan using xif1vm_ip_address_histories on vm_ip_address_histories d  (cost=0.29..70.34 rows=8 width=15) (actual time=0.011..0.921 rows=3 loops=61)
                           Index Cond: (vm_id = c.vm_id)
                           Filter: ((allocation_date <= last_day(sysdate())) AND ((deallocation_date IS NULL) OR (deallocation_date > last_day(sysdate()))))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 84
               ->  Hash  (cost=1280129.06..1280129.06 rows=1575435 width=23) (actual time=13130.223..13130.223 rows=203702 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 8192  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 422kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on ip_address_usage_histories e  (cost=0.00..1280129.06 rows=1575435 width=23) (actual time=0.205..13002.776 rows=203702 loops=1)
                           Filter: (datetime >= firstday())
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 4522813
 Planning time: 0.804 ms
 Execution time: 13221.155 ms
(27 rows)
```

Notice that the planner is choosing to perform a very expensive full table scans on the largest tables - `ip_address_usage_histories` and `vm_ip_address_histories`.  I have tried changing the configuration parameter `enable_seqscan` to off, but that made the problem worse, total execution time went to 63 seconds.

Here are the describes of the aforementioned tables:

```
                             Table "ip_address_usage_histories"
           Column            |            Type             | Modifiers 
-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 ip_address_usage_history_id | bigint                      | not null
 datetime                    | timestamp without time zone | not null
 ip_address                  | inet                        | not null
 bytes_sent                  | bigint                      | not null
 bytes_received              | bigint                      | not null
Indexes:
    "ip_address_usage_histories_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ip_address_usage_history_id)
    "ip_address_usage_histories_datetime_ip_address_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (datetime, ip_address)
    "uk_mit6tbiu8k62vdae4tmtnwb3f" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (datetime, ip_address)
```

```
                          Table "vm_ip_address_histories"
          Column          |            Type             |                                         Modifiers                                          
--------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 vm_ip_address_history_id | bigint                      | not null default nextval('vm_ip_address_histories_vm_ip_address_history_id_seq'::regclass)
 ip_address               | inet                        | not null
 allocation_date          | timestamp without time zone | not null
 deallocation_date        | timestamp without time zone | 
 vm_id                    | bigint                      | not null
Indexes:
    "vm_ip_address_histories_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (vm_ip_address_history_id)
    "xie1vm_ip_address_histories" btree (replicate_date)
    "xif1vm_ip_address_histories" btree (vm_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "vm_ip_address_histories_vm_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (vm_id) REFERENCES vms(vm_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

It appears that Postgres does not have query hints to direct the planner.  I also tried the from clause `inner join ... on ...` syntax, but that did not improve things either.

---

Update 1

```
create or replace function firstday() returns timestamp without time zone as $$
begin
   return date_trunc('month',now()::timestamp without time zone)::timestamp without time zone;
end; $$
language plpgsql;
```

I have not tried to replace this function with a standard function because Postgres doesn't have a function that returns the first day of the month to my knowledge.

Comment: How is the function `firstday()` defined? Is that defined as `stable` or `immutable`? And what exactly does it do? Does the query change when you replace it with a SQL standard function like `current_timestamp` or something similar?

Comment: What happens when you use the `date_trunc()` expression directly: `and e.datetime >= date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)`? Does Postgres use the index then? You should also try to define the function as `stable`, maybe it being `volatile` prevents the planner from using the index.

Comment: I tried to use date_trunc first when I saw it wasn't using the index.

Answer (score 0):

The following was embedded in the question, but it reads as an answer.

---

After changing the all of my functions to immutable, the query now runs in 200ms!  All the right things are happening.

```
                              QUERY PLAN                                                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=51865.24..51914.88 rows=1103 width=24) (actual time=178.793..188.223 rows=7 loops=1)
   Group Key: c.vm_name
   ->  Sort  (cost=51865.24..51868.00 rows=1103 width=24) (actual time=178.517..180.541 rows=13823 loops=1)
         Sort Key: c.vm_name
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1464kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=50289.49..51809.50 rows=1103 width=24) (actual time=131.278..155.971 rows=13823 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (d.ip_address = e.ip_address)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.97..272.36 rows=23 width=15) (actual time=0.149..2.310 rows=192 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.69..41.02 rows=98 width=16) (actual time=0.046..0.590 rows=61 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (c.group_id = b.group_id)
                           ->  Seq Scan on vms c  (cost=0.00..30.98 rows=1698 width=24) (actual time=0.006..0.250 rows=1698 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=2.65..2.65 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=4 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on groups b  (cost=0.00..2.65 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.012 rows=4 loops=1)
                                       Filter: (customer_id = 29)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 49
                     ->  Index Scan using xif1vm_ip_address_histories on vm_ip_address_histories d  (cost=0.29..2.34 rows=2 width=15) (actual time=0.002..0.027 rows=3 loops=61)
                           Index Cond: (vm_id = c.vm_id)
                           Filter: ((allocation_date <= '2015-03-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((deallocation_date IS NULL) OR (deallocation_date > '2015-03-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 84
               ->  Hash  (cost=46621.83..46621.83 rows=199575 width=23) (actual time=130.762..130.762 rows=206266 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 8192  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 2818kB
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ip_address_usage_histories e  (cost=4627.14..46621.83 rows=199575 width=23) (actual time=18.335..69.763 rows=206266 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: (datetime >= '2015-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                           Heap Blocks: exact=3684
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on uk_mit6tbiu8k62vdae4tmtnwb3f  (cost=0.00..4577.24 rows=199575 width=0) (actual time=17.797..17.797 rows=206935 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (datetime >= '2015-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
 Planning time: 0.837 ms
 Execution time: 188.301 ms
(29 rows)
```

I now see the planner is executing the functions, and using their values to insert into the where clause, which causes the indexes to be used.